# Kernel 3.8 support for beaglebone black Yocto project

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am using beaglebone balck and Chipsee LCD.
I buit Yocto project for beaglebone black and found that it has latest kernel i.e. Linux 3.14
but Chipsee LCD patch what i have is for Linux kernel 3.8.
So i want to build yocto project for linux kernel 3.8. Is it possible ? if yes how ?
Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

EDIT:
After referring Yocto documentation i found that kernel 3.8 is supported in the Yocto project version "YP Core - Dylan 1.4.3" but i think It doesn't support Beaglebone black BSP, If that is the case my question is If latest yocto project "YP Core - Daisy 1.6.1" supports linux kernel 3.8 or not ?

EDIT:

3.14 is booting up with Chipsee LCD:

[Chipsee 7 inch LCD support in Linux kernel 3.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156008/chipsee-7-inch-lcd-support-in-linux-kernel-3-14)

Comment: of course it is not officially supported:  https://www.yoctoproject.org/downloads/core/daisy16  only 3.10 and 3.14, LTSI version.   but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156008/chipsee-7-inch-lcd-support-in-linux-kernel-3-14 you indicated that it can boot 3.14.   please update your posting.