# Chipsee 7 inch LCD support in Linux kernel 3.14

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, lcd

Has anybody ported Chipsee 7 inch LCD on Linux kernel 3.14 or later ?

Is there any patch available for the same ?

If no patches any suggestion porting Chipsee LCD support from Linux kernel 3.8 to Linux kernel 3.14 ?

Update:

```
`/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include "am335x-bone-common.dtsi"

&ldo3_reg {
    regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-always-on;
};
/*
&mmc1 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
};

&mmc2 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_pins>;
    bus-width = <8>;
    status = "okay";
    ti,vcc-aux-disable-is-sleep;
};
*/
&am33xx_pinmux {
               userled_pins: pinmux_userled_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x98 0x7    /* gpmc_wen.gpio2_4, OUTPUT | MODE7 */
                0x9c 0x7    /* gpmc_ben0_cle.gpio2_5, OUTPUT | MODE7 */
                        >;
                };
                i2c0_pins: pinmux_i2c0_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x188 0x70      /* i2c0_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                                0x18c 0x70      /* i2c0_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE0 */
                        >;
                };
                i2c1_pins: pinmux_i2c1_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x158 0x72      /* spi0_d1.i2c1_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                                0x15c 0x72      /* spi0_cs0.i2c1_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                        >;
                };
                mmc1_pins: pinmux_mmc1_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x160 0x2f /* GPIO0_6 (PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) */
                        >;
                };
        rstctl_pins: pinmux_rstctl_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                /* eMMC_RSTn */
                0x50 0x17   /* gpmc_a4.gpio1_20, OUTPUT | MODE7 | PULLUP */
            >;
        };
        chipsee_lcd_pins: pinmux_chipsee_lcd_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0xa0 0x00       /* lcd_data0.lcd_data0, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xa4 0x00       /* lcd_data1.lcd_data1, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xa8 0x00       /* lcd_data2.lcd_data2, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xac 0x00       /* lcd_data3.lcd_data3, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xb0 0x00       /* lcd_data4.lcd_data4, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xb4 0x00       /* lcd_data5.lcd_data5, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xb8 0x00       /* lcd_data6.lcd_data6, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xbc 0x00       /* lcd_data7.lcd_data7, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xc0 0x00       /* lcd_data8.lcd_data8, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xc4 0x00       /* lcd_data9.lcd_data9, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xc8 0x00       /* lcd_data10.lcd_data10, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xcc 0x00       /* lcd_data11.lcd_data11, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xd0 0x00       /* lcd_data12.lcd_data12, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xd4 0x00       /* lcd_data13.lcd_data13, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xd8 0x00       /* lcd_data14.lcd_data14, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xdc 0x00       /* lcd_data15.lcd_data15, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x3c 0x11       /* gpmc_ad15.lcd_data16, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x38 0x11       /* gpmc_ad14.lcd_data17, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x34 0x11       /* gpmc_ad13.lcd_data18, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x30 0x11       /* gpmc_ad12.lcd_data19, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x2c 0x11       /* gpmc_ad11.lcd_data20, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x28 0x11       /* gpmc_ad10.lcd_data21, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x24 0x11       /* gpmc_ad9.lcd_data22, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0x20 0x11       /* gpmc_ad8.lcd_data23, OMAP_MUX_MODE1 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xe0 0x00       /* lcd_vsync.lcd_vsync, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xe4 0x00       /* lcd_hsync.lcd_hsync, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xe8 0x00       /* lcd_pclk.lcd_pclk, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
                0xec 0x00       /* lcd_ac_bias_en.lcd_ac_bias_en, OMAP_MUX_MODE0 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
            >;
        };

        pwm_bl_pins: pinmux_pwm_bl_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x48 0x06       /* gpmc_a2.ehrpwm1a, OMAP_MUX_MODE6 | AM33XX_PIN_OUTPUT */
            >;
        };
        chipsee_gpio_pins: pinmux_chipsee_gpio_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x044 0x27      /* CAP_TSC gpmc_a1.gpio1_17, INPUT | MODE7 */
                0x094 0x07      /* BUZZER gpmc_oen_ren.gpio2_3 OUTPUT | MODE7 */
            >;      
        };

        chipsee_gpio_keys_pins: pinmux_chipsee_gpio_keys_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x164 0x2f      /* KEY_LEFT ecap0_in_pwm0_out.gpio0_7, INPUT | PULLDIS | MODE7 */
                0x078 0x2f      /* KEY_RIGHT gpmc_ben1.gpio1_28, INPUT | PULLDIS | MODE7 */
                0x040 0x2f      /* KEY_UP gpmc_a0.gpio1_16, INPUT | PULLDIS | MODE7 */
                0x04c 0x2f      /* KEY_DOWN gpmc_a3.gpio1_19, INPUT | PULLDIS | MODE7 */
                0x1a4 0x2f      /* KEY_ENTER mcasp0_fxr.gpio3_19, INPUT | PULLDIS | MODE7 */
            >;
        };

                chipsee_uart1_pins: pinmux_chipsee_uart1_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x180 0x20 /* uart1_rxd.uart1_rxd  INPUT | MODE0 */
                                0x184 0x00 /* uart1_txd.uart1_txd  OUTPUT | MODE0 */
                        >;
                };

                chipsee_uart2_pins: pinmux_chipsee_uart2_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x150 0x21      /* spi0_sclk.uart2_rxd INPUT | MODE1 */
                                0x154 0x01      /* spi0_d0.uart2_txd OUTPUT | MODE1 */
                        >;
                };

                chipsee_uart4_pins: pinmux_chipsee_uart4_pins {
                        pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                0x070 0x26      /* gpmc_wait0.uart4_rxd INPUT | MODE6 */
                                0x074 0x06      /* gpmc_wpn.uart4_txd OUTPUT | MODE6 */
                        >;
                };

        chipsee_dcan0_pins: pinmux_chipsee_dcan0_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x178 0x02      /* uart1_ctsn.d_can0_tx OUTPUT | MODE2 */
                0x17c 0x32      /* uart1_rtsn.d_can0_rx INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
            >;
        };
        chipsee_audio_pins: pinmux_chipsee_audio_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                0x190 0x20      /* mcasp0_aclkx.mcasp0_aclkx, INPUT | MODE0 */
                0x194 0x20      /* mcasp0_fsx.mcasp0_fsx, INPUT | MODE0 */
                0x198 0x20      /* mcasp0_axr0.mcasp0_axr0, INPUT | MODE0 */
                0x19c 0x22      /* mcasp0_ahclkr.mcasp0_axr2, INPUT | MODE2 */
            >;
        };
};

        /*
         * To consider voltage drop between PMIC and SoC,
         * tolerance value is reduced to 2% from 4% and
         * voltage value is increased as a precaution.
         */

    /* kHz    uV */
/*
&cpus {

    &cpu@0 {

        operating-points = <

                1000000 1350000
                800000  1300000
                600000  1112000
                300000   969000
        >;
    };
};
*/
/{

ocp {

                uartt0:serial@44e09000 {
                        status = "okay";
                };

/*
                epwmss1: epwmss@48302000 {
                        status = "okay";

                        ehrpwm1: ehrpwm@48302200 {
                                status = "okay";
                                pinctrl-names = "default";
                                pinctrl-0 = <&pwm_bl_pins>;
                        };
                };
*/


/*      backlight {
            compatible      = "pwm-backlight";
            pwms = <&ehrpwm1 0 500000 0>;
            brightness-levels = <0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100>;
            default-brightness-level = <101>; 
        };
index to the array above 

*/
                gpio-leds {
                        compatible = "gpio-leds";
                        pinctrl-names = "default";
                        pinctrl-0 = <&userled_pins>;

                        led0 {
                                label = "beaglebone:green:usr0";
                                gpios = <&gpio3 4 0>;
                                linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
                                default-state = "off";
                        };

                        led1 {
                                label = "beaglebone:green:usr1";
                                gpios = <&gpio3 5 0>;
                                linux,default-trigger = "mmc0";
                                default-state = "off";
                        };
                };

        gpio_keys {
            compatible = "gpio-keys";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_gpio_keys_pins>;

            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            button@1 {
                debounce_interval = <50>;
                linux,code = <105>;
                label = "left";
                gpios = <&gpio1 7 0x1>;
                gpio-key,wakeup;
                autorepeat;
            };
            button@2 {
                debounce_interval = <50>;
                linux,code = <106>;
                label = "right";
                gpios = <&gpio2 28 0x1>;
                gpio-key,wakeup;
                autorepeat;
            };
            button@3 {
                debounce_interval = <50>;
                linux,code = <103>;
                label = "up";
                gpios = <&gpio2 16 0x1>;
                gpio-key,wakeup;
                autorepeat;
            };
            button@4 {
                debounce_interval = <50>;
                linux,code = <108>;
                label = "down";
                gpios = <&gpio2 19 0x1>;
                gpio-key,wakeup;
                autorepeat;
            };
            button@5 {
                debounce_interval = <50>;
                linux,code = <28>;
                label = "enter";
                gpios = <&gpio3 19 0x1>;
                gpio-key,wakeup;
            };
        };

        gpio_setups {
            compatible = "gpio-of-helper";
            status = "okay";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_gpio_pins>;

            /* declare your gpios */
            cap_touch_int {
                gpio-name = "cap_touch_int";
                gpio = <&gpio2 17 0x00>;
                input;
            };

            buzzer {
                gpio-name = "buzzer";
                gpio = <&gpio3 3 0x00>;
                output;
                init-low;
            };
        };

                rtc@44e3e000 {
                        ti,system-power-controller;
                status = "okay";
                };

                panel {
                        compatible = "tilcdc,panel";
                        pinctrl-names = "default";
                        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_lcd_pins>;
                        panel-info {
                                ac-bias           = <255>;
                                ac-bias-intrpt    = <0>;
                                dma-burst-sz      = <16>;
                                bpp               = <32>;
                                fdd               = <0x80>;
                                tft-alt-mode      = <0>;
                                stn-565-mode      = <0>;
                                mono-8bit-mode    = <0>;
                                sync-edge         = <0>;
                                sync-ctrl         = <0>;
                                raster-order      = <1>;
                                fifo-th           = <0>;
                        };
                        display-timings {
                                native-mode = <&timing0>;
                                timing0: 1024x600 {
                                        hactive         = <1024>;
                                        vactive         = <600>;
                                        hback-porch     = <45>;
                                        hfront-porch    = <1>;
                                        hsync-len       = <30>;
                                        vback-porch     = <22>;
                                        vfront-porch    = <12>;
                                        vsync-len       = <2>;
                                        clock-frequency = <36000000>;
                                        hsync-active    = <1>;
                                        vsync-active    = <1>;
                                };
                        };
        };


                fb {
                        compatible = "ti,am33xx-tilcdc";
                        reg = <0x4830e000 0x1000>;
                        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
                        interrupts = <36>;
                        ti,hwmods = "lcdc";
                        ti,allow-non-reduced-blanking-modes;
                };

                tscadc {
                        compatible = "ti,ti-tscadc";
                        reg = <0x44e0d000 0x1000>;

                        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
                        interrupts = <16>;
                        ti,hwmods = "adc_tsc";
                        status = "okay";

                        tsc {
                                ti,wires = <4>;
                                ti,x-plate-resistance = <200>;
                                ti,steps-to-config= <5>;
                                ti,x-min= <0xCB>;
                                ti,x-max= <0xFFF>;
                                ti,x-inverted= <0>;
                                ti,y-min= <0xC8>;
                                ti,y-max= <0xFFF>;
                                ti,y-inverted= <0>;
                        };

                        adc {
                                ti,adc-channels = <4 5 6 7>;
                        };
                };

        sound {
            compatible = "ti,da830-evm-audio";
            ti,model = "DA830 EVM";
            ti,audio-codec = <&tlv320aic3x>;
            ti,mcasp-controller = <&mcasp0>;
            ti,codec-clock-rate = <12000000>;
            ti,audio-routing =
                "Headphone Jack",       "HPLOUT",
                "Headphone Jack",       "HPROUT",
                "MIC3L",                "Mic Bias 2V",
                "MIC3R",                "Mic Bias 2V",
                "Mic Bias 2V",          "Mic Jack";
        };

      };

};
&mcasp0 {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_audio_pins>;

        status = "okay";

        op-mode = <0>;          /* MCASP_IIS_MODE */
        tdm-slots = <2>;
        num-serializer = <16>;
        serial-dir = <  /* 0: INACTIVE, 1: TX, 2: RX */
                1 0 2 0
                0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 0
        >;
        tx-num-evt = <1>;
        rx-num-evt = <1>;
};

&i2c0 {
        status = "okay";
        clock-frequency = <400000>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&i2c0_pins>;

        tps: tps@24 {
                reg = <0x24>;
        };

        baseboard_eeprom: baseboard_eeprom@50 {
                compatible = "at,24c256";
                reg = <0x50>;
        };
};

&i2c1 {
        status = "okay";
        clock-frequency = <400000>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;

        ft5x06_ts: ft5x06_ts@38 {
                compatible = "ft5x06_ts";
                reg = <0x38>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
                interrupts = <17>;
        };

        tlv320aic3x: tlv320aic3x@1b {
                compatible = "ti,tlv320aic3x";
                reg = <0x1b>;
                status = "okay";
        };
};

#include "tps65217.dtsi"

&tps {
        ti,pmic-shutdown-controller;

        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
        interrupts = <7>;       /* NNMI */

        regulators {
                dcdc1_reg: regulator@0 {
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                dcdc2_reg: regulator@1 {
                        /* VDD_MPU voltage limits 0.95V - 1.26V with +/-4% tolerance */
                        regulator-name = "vdd_mpu";
                        regulator-min-microvolt = <925000>;
                        regulator-max-microvolt = <1325000>;
                        regulator-boot-on;
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                dcdc3_reg: regulator@2 {
                        /* VDD_CORE voltage limits 0.95V - 1.1V with +/-4% tolerance */
                        regulator-name = "vdd_core";
                        regulator-min-microvolt = <925000>;
                        regulator-max-microvolt = <1150000>;
                        regulator-boot-on;
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                ldo1_reg: regulator@3 {
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                ldo2_reg: regulator@4 {
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                ldo3_reg: regulator@5 {
                        regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
                        regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
                        regulator-always-on;
                };

                ldo4_reg: regulator@6 {
                        regulator-always-on;
                };
    };
};

&uart1 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_uart1_pins>;
};

&uart2 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_uart2_pins>;
};

&uart4 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_uart4_pins>;
};

&dcan0 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&chipsee_dcan0_pins>;
};

&cpsw_emac0 {
        phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <0>;
};

&cpsw_emac1 {
        phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <1>;
};

&mmc1 {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&mmc1_pins>;
        bus-width = <0x4>;
        cd-gpios = <&gpio1 6 0>; /* gpio1 is misnamed, 0 == GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH */
        cd-inverted;
        status = "okay";
        vmmc-supply = <&ldo3_reg>;
        ti,vcc-aux-disable-is-sleep;
};

&edma {
        ti,edma-xbar-event-map = <32 12>,       /* gpevt2 -> 12 */
                                 <30 20>;       /* xdma_event_intr2 -> 20 */
};

&sham {
        status = "okay";
};

&aes {
        status = "okay";
};

&usb {
        interface_type = <1>;
        power = <250>;
        status = "okay";
};

&ldo3_reg {
    regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-always-on;
};

/*
rstctl {
    status = "okay";
    compatible = "gpio-rctrl";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&rstctl_pins>;

    #reset-cells = <2>;

    gpios = <&gpio2 20 0x00>;
    gpio-names = "eMMC_RSTn";
};

*/
&mmc1 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
};
/*
&mmc2 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
    bus-width = <8>;
    ti,non-removable;
    status = "disabled";

    reset = <&rstctl 0 0>;
    reset-names = "eMMC_RSTn-CONSUMER";
};
*/

`
```

After changing devicetree as above, i get following output,

```
  UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
    NET: Registered protocol family 1
    RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
    RPC: Registered udp transport module.
    RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
    RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
    hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
    futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
    NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
    Key type id_resolver registered
    Key type id_legacy registered
    msgmni has been set to 987
    Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
    io scheduler noop registered
    io scheduler deadline registered
    io scheduler cfq registered (default)
    pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins at pa f9e10800 size 568
    omap_uart 44e09000.serial: no wakeirq for uart0
    44e09000.serial: ttyO0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 88, base_baud = 3000000) is a O                                                                                MAP UART0
    omap_uart 48022000.serial: no wakeirq for uart0
    48022000.serial: ttyO1 at MMIO 0x48022000 (irq = 89, base_baud = 3000000) is a O                                                                                MAP UART1
    console [ttyO1] enabled
    omap_uart 48024000.serial: no wakeirq for uart0
    48024000.serial: ttyO2 at MMIO 0x48024000 (irq = 90, base_baud = 3000000) is a O                                                                                MAP UART2
    omap_uart 481a8000.serial: no wakeirq for uart0
    481a8000.serial: ttyO4 at MMIO 0x481a8000 (irq = 61, base_baud = 3000000) is a O                                                                                MAP UART4
    [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
    brd: module loaded
    mtdoops: mtd device (mtddev=name/number) must be supplied
    usbcore: registered new interface driver kaweth
    pegasus: v0.9.3 (2013/04/25), Pegasus/Pegasus II USB Ethernet driver
    usbcore: registered new interface driver pegasus
    usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8150
    usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
    usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a
    usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
    usbcore: registered new interface driver dm9601
    usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc75xx
    usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
    usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
    usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
    usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
    usbcore: registered new interface driver MOSCHIP usb-ethernet driver
    usbcore: registered new interface driver int51x1
    usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
    ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
    ehci-omap: OMAP-EHCI Host Controller driver
    usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
    omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: rtc core: registered 44e3e000.rtc as rtc0
    i2c /dev entries driver
    omap_wdt: OMAP Watchdog Timer Rev 0x01: initial timeout 60 sec
    48060000.mmc supply vmmc_aux not found, using dummy regulator
    usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    usbhid: USB HID core driver
    oprofile: using arm/armv7
    u32 classifier
        Actions configured
    TCP: cubic registered
    NET: Registered protocol family 10
    sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
    NET: Registered protocol family 17
    Key type dns_resolver registered
    ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
    bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
    Btrfs loaded
    vmmcsd_fixed: disabling
    regulator-dummy: disabling
    tilcdc 4830e000.fb: no encoders/connectors found
    tilcdc 4830e000.fb: failed to initialize mode setting
    DCDC1: at 1500 mV
    vdd_mpu: 925 <--> 1325 mV at 1100 mV
    vdd_core: 925 <--> 1150 mV at 1100 mV
    LDO1: at 1800 mV
    LDO2: at 3300 mV
    LDO3: 1800 mV
    LDO4: at 3300 mV
    tps65217 0-0024: TPS65217 ID 0xe version 1.2
    omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: bus 0 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
    omap_i2c 4802a000.i2c: bus 1 rev0.11 at 400 kHz
    console [netcon0] enabled
    netconsole: network logging started
    davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6
    davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
    libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
    davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710                                                                                /LAN8720
    Detected MACID = 90:59:af:5b:ec:e5
    input: gpio_keys.5 as /devices/ocp.3/gpio_keys.5/input/input0
    omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (94668480                                                                                0)
    VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk0p2" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
    Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
    VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
    User configuration error - no valid root filesystem found
    Kernel panic - not syncing: Invalid configuration from end user prevents continu                                                                                ing
    CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 3.14.0-yocto-standard #1
    [<c0014fa8>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c00123d8>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
    [<c00123d8>] (show_stack) from [<c06b8bc4>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
    [<c06b8bc4>] (dump_stack) from [<c06b48f8>] (panic+0x8c/0x1c8)
    [<c06b48f8>] (panic) from [<c09c1194>] (mount_block_root+0x1fc/0x244)
    [<c09c1194>] (mount_block_root) from [<c09c13ac>] (mount_root+0xe8/0x10c)
    [<c09c13ac>] (mount_root) from [<c09c1534>] (prepare_namespace+0x164/0x1c4)
    [<c09c1534>] (prepare_namespace) from [<c09c0d4c>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x228/0                                                                                x278)
    [<c09c0d4c>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c06b3c54>] (kernel_init+0x1c/0xf4)
    [<c06b3c54>] (kernel_init) from [<c000e338>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20)
    ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦
```

Comment: where are the sources, what have you tried ?

Comment: Thank you for attention, so far i have 3.8 kernel and dts provided by chipsee, according to which i am trying to change it in Yocto project for beagblebone black. Well i am not well versed with Yocto project so actually stuck with building dtb. I will update result once i get through.

Comment: forgot to mention that, Yocto project with kernel 3.14.

Comment: I have made some more progress and now i am able to boot the BBB & chipsee LCD with Linux kernel 3.14, some of the imp file i have upated under [github repo](https://github.com/AnkurTank/chipsee_kernel3.14_support.git)

Comment: cool, since u have answered your own question put it up as a answer, and i will +1 it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Peter, I would love to answer my own question not for getting +1 but for supporting others in the same way i get support here. But problem is I don't have complete solution to this problem. And this being my side project I am going slow on this. Once i have complete solution I will put the answer for sure.

Comment: I'm currently struggling to achieve something similar. I have a display that works under 3.13, but not under Ubuntu 18 (4.14). I will have a closer look now, thanks for sharing your experience! (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181645/how-to-make-a-tilcdc-display-work-in-ubuntu-18)

Comment: @Robert I hope you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723261/building-robert-nelsons-linux-kernel-into-yoctodaisy-for-beaglebone-black

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's on my "study list" - I'm off for today :-)