# Building Robert Nelson's Linux kernel into Yocto(daisy) for beaglebone black

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, beagleboneblack, yocto

I was trying to build Linux for beaglebone black from official repository https://github.com/beagleboard/linux

I am able to fetch and run menuconfig but when i try to compile the kernel i get error.

Following is the content of the recipe file.

**File name** : linux-yocto-chipsee_3.14.bb
**path**: /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/meta-ybdevelop/recipes-example/linux

```
inherit kernel
require recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.inc

BRANCH = "3.14"
# Override SRC_URI in a bbappend file to point at a different source # tree if you do not want to build from Linus' tree.
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/beagleboard/linux.git;branch=${BRANCH};nocheckout=1;name=machine"

LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.14"
LINUX_VERSION_EXTENSION ?= "-custom"

# Override SRCREV to point to a different commit in a bbappend file to # build a different release of the Linux kernel.
# tag: v3.4 76e10d158efb6d4516018846f60c2ab5501900bc
SRCREV_machine="76e10d158efb6d4516018846f60c2ab5501900bc"

PR = "r1"
PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"

# Override COMPATIBLE_MACHINE to include your machine in a bbappend # file. Leaving it empty here ensures an early explicit build failure.
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "beaglebone"
```

**File name** :linux-yocto-chipsee_3.14.bbappend
**File path** : /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/meta-ybdevelop/recipes-example/linux

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}-${PV}:"
SRC_URI_append = " file://defconfig"
```

**defconfig path**: /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/meta-ybdevelop/recipes-example/linux/linux-yocto-chipsee_3.14

With above configuration i am able to fetch and open menuconfig for fetched linux kernel, command i used is as follows,

```
# bitbake linux-yocto-chipsee -c menuconfig
```

But when I try to compile Linux using below command it gives error,

```
# bitbake linux-yocto-chipsee -c compile
```

getting error related to gcc :(

```
 /bin/sh: 1: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
| make[4]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
| make[3]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
|   SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.c
|   Generating include/generated/mach-types.h
|   SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.hash.c
|   SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.h
|   SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.c
|   HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
|   CC      kernel/bounds.s
| /bin/sh: 1: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
```

When i try to build using below command that time also it failed.

```
# bitbake linux-yocto-chipsee -c build

ERROR: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide virtual/kernel (/home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/meta-ybdevelop/recipes-example/linux/linux-yocto-chipsee_3.14.bb /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_3.14.bb).
 This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/build_fresh/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto-chipsee/3.14+gitAUTOINC+76e10d158e-r1/temp/log.do_compile.30878)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ankur/yocto_daisy/poky/build_fresh/tmp/work/beaglebone-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto-chipsee/3.14+gitAUTOINC+76e10d158e-r1/temp/log.do_compile.30878
```

Bitbake layers for linux shows below output

Just FYI:

```
# bitbake-layers show-recipes 'linux*'

Parsing recipes..done.
=== Available recipes matching linux*: ===
linux-dummy:
  meta                 1.0
linux-firmware:
  meta                 1:0.0+gitAUTOINC+600caefd83
linux-libc-headers:
  meta                 3.14
linux-yocto:
  meta                 3.14.4+gitAUTOINC+183622e809_0143c6ebb4
  meta                 3.10 (skipped)
  meta                 3.4 (skipped)
linux-yocto-chipsee:
  meta-ybdevelop       3.14+gitAUTOINC+76e10d158e
linux-yocto-dev:
  meta                 unknown (skipped)
linux-yocto-rt:
  meta                 3.10 (skipped)
  meta                 3.14 (skipped)
  meta                 3.4 (skipped)
linux-yocto-tiny:
  meta                 3.10 (skipped)
  meta                 3.14 (skipped)
  meta                 3.4 (skipped)
linuxdoc-tools-native:
  meta                 0.9.69
linuxptp:
  meta-oe              1.4
```

Any help/pointer/hint/suggestions to compile this ?

Thank you,

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: Did you launch setup_environment script? Didi you configure the local.conf and bblayers.conf correctly?

Comment: Thank you for debugging hints, Yes indeed i had lunched setup_env script. that's the reason bitbake command for menuconfig works. I had added meta-ydevelop in the bblayers.conf file. But i didn't change anything in local.conf for changing kernel. local.conf contains MACHINE ?= "beaglebone".

Comment: Did you try to compile the standard poky recipe core-image-base or corre-image-minimal?

Comment: Thank you for help, I had compiled core-image-sato and it works fine. Only problem is with that my Chipsee 7 inch LCD doesn't work. And i read in BBB forum that Robert Nelson's Linux branch has support for  the same. After compiling that kernel if use `am335x-boneblack-bbb-exp-c.dts` my Chipsee LCD should boot. reference : https://www.mail-archive.com/beagleboard@googlegroups.com/msg22535.html

Answer (score 0):

Well for time being i downloaded the Yocto_daisy(1.6) toolchain and installed it in my PC. And compiled the Linux external to Yocto build. Here are steps.
I followed below steps in my virtualbox installed ubuntu.

1. in Yocto_daisy build core-image-sato, using following command,

   bitbake core-image-sato
2. Prepare micro SD card with rootfile system, SPL & U-Boot, uImage, dtb, uEnv.txt.
3. Clone beaglebone black Linux using following command

   git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/beagleboard/linux
4. Download yocto-1.6(daisy) toolchain from following link.

   http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-1.6/toolchain/
   Based on your machine type download from either i686 or x86_64
   I downloaded following toochain.
   http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/yocto/yocto-1.6/toolchain/i686/poky-eglibc-i686-core-image-sato-armv7a-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.6.sh
5. Install toolchain by running download toolchain script. By default it installs into opt directory, I installed it in default path.
6. In terminal traverse to the above downloaded Linux directory. and set toolchain environment by running following command,

   source /opt/poky/1.6/environment-setup-armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
7. Now configure kernel using following command,

make bb.org_defconfig

8. and then build kernel using following command

   make uImage LOADADDR=0x80008000 -j4
9. now we shall install the modules into local directory using following commands,

   mkdir bbb_modules
    export INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/home/ankur/linux/bbb_modules/
    make modules_install
10. when kernel is built copy `uImage`(from /arch/arm/boot) and `am335x-boneblack-bbb-exp-c.dtb`(from  /arch/arm/boot) to the BOOT partition of the micro SD card.

For FYI my uEnv.txt looks like this

```
Disable: HDMI
bootargs=console=ttyO1,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rw rootwait;
bootcmd=mmc rescan ; mmc dev 0 ; fatload mmc 0 0x80007fc0 uImage ; fatload mmc 0 0x80F80000 am335x-boneblack-bbb-exp-c.dtb ; echo Ankur... ${bootcmd}; bootm 0x80007fc0 - 0x80F80000;
uenvcmd=boot;
```

11 . Now copy modules from local directory to the micro SD card, using following commands,

```
cp -a /home/ankur/linux/bbb_modules/lib /media/ankur/ROOT/
sync
```

12. Eject the card put it into Beaglbone Black and power on the BBB+LCD.

I am yet to get the Touch calibration working for LCD but once I find it i will update the answer.

Another pending thing is build above kernel into Yocto build system. I will update the answer once i am done with that.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.